# Prove that the inequality is valid if $x,y,z$ are positive numbers and $xyz=1.$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, geometric-inequalities

Is given that $x,y,z$ are positive numbers and $xyz=1$, prove that
$$\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{x}}{\sqrt{z^2+1}}+\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{y}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}+\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{z}} {\sqrt{y^2+1}}>\sqrt{2}.$$
What have I done?
First, rewrite our inequality as a function
$$f(x,y,z)=\dfrac{1}{x \sqrt{z^2+1}}+\dfrac{1}{y \sqrt{x^2+1}}+\dfrac{1}{z \sqrt{y^2+1}}-\sqrt{2}.$$

Second, I used this:
$a^2+b^2 \geq 2c.$
So, we got
$$\dfrac{1}{x \sqrt{z^2+1}}+\dfrac{1}{y \sqrt{x^2+1}}+\dfrac{1}{z \sqrt{y^2+1}}-\sqrt{2} \geq \dfrac{1}{x \sqrt{2z}}+\dfrac{1}{y\sqrt{(2x}}+\dfrac{1}{z*\sqrt{2y}}-\sqrt{2}.$$

Further I used this:
$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{ab}} \geq \dfrac{2}{a+b}.$
We got
$$\dfrac{1}{x\sqrt{2z}}+\dfrac{1}{y\sqrt{2x}}+\dfrac{1}{z\sqrt{2y}}-\sqrt{2} \geq \dfrac{2}{x(2+z)}+\dfrac{2}{y(2+x)}+\dfrac{2}{z(2+y)}-\sqrt{2}.$$

The next step is to use this:
$$\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{c}{d}+\dfrac{e}{f} \geq 3 \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{ace}{dbf}}.$$
And we got
$$\dfrac{2}{x(2+z)}+\dfrac{2}{y(2+x)}+\dfrac{2}{z(2+y)}-\sqrt{2} \geq 3\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{8}{xyz(2+x)(2+y)(2+z)}}-\sqrt{2} .$$

What I did next is raised both sides of the inequality to the sixth power
$$3^6  \dfrac{8}{xyz(2+z)(2+x)(2+y)} \geq 2 \sqrt{2}$$ and
$$3^6  \dfrac{8}{xyz(2+z)(2+x)(2+y)}-2 \sqrt{2} \geq 0.$$
I don't know what to do next and how to show that it is greater than zero?
Any hint would help a lot! Thanks!

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial

Comment: J. W. Tanner thank you very much!

Comment: I did the mathjax but I don't know what are last notations that you wrote @AliceMalinova

Comment: PNT thank you very much! it's my mistake, there is \sqrt instead of \dfrac

Comment: There is an error early in your calculations. $z^2+1 \ge 2 z$ implies that $\frac{1}{x\sqrt{z^2+1}} \color{red}{\le} \frac{1}{x\sqrt{2z}}$.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood right your problem.

Let $x=\frac{a}{b},$ $y=\frac{b}{c}$, where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positives.

Thus, $z=\frac{c}{a}$ and by AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{x\sqrt{z^2+1}}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\frac{a}{b}\sqrt{1+\frac{c^2}{a^2}}}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+c^2}}=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\frac{2b^2}{2\sqrt{b^2(a^2+c^2)}}\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{2b^2}{b^2+a^2+c^2}=2>\sqrt2.$$
Because $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{2b^2}{b^2+a^2+c^2}=\frac{2b^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}+\frac{2c^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}+\frac{2a^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}=2.$$
Your solution is wrong because by AM-GM $$\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1+z^2}}\leq\frac{1}{x\cdot\sqrt{2z}}.$$

Comment: Michael Rosenberg great substitution! How can I think of that I need to use exactly this one..

Comment: a bit unclear the last step when fraction is equal to 2. Can you explain please?

Comment: @Alice Malinova It's just homogenization because $\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{b}{c}\cdot\frac{c}{a}=1$. I added something. See now.

Comment: I see now! Thank you very much! How do you think is it really possible to do something worthwhile with my solution or is it completely hopeless?

Comment: @Alice Malinova You are welcome! I added something again.

Comment: I see now! thank you again!

Comment: I have one more question-what would be if we replace the right side with 2? Then the inequality is invalid, right?

Comment: @Alice Malinova If we replace the right side with 2, so the inequality would be true.